# Set a maximum depth of JSON serialization in .NET Web API

Tags: .net, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

Let's say I have these entitites with these relations: *This is just a fictious example, and not my current entities.*

- Course
- User
- NewsPosts

Courses have many Users,
Users have many Courses

Courses has many NewsPosts,
NewsPosts has many Courses

Users has many NewsPosts,
NewsPosts has Many Users

I'm using Entity Framework code first with .NET Web API, which sends back entities in the form of JSON. When I try to Get a Course, it sends back a JSON result with the relations of the entites, which is fine, but I would wish to set a limit of how many levels it serializes so it does not serialize all the relations beyond the first or second level.

GET Course/ would be serialized to:

```
   {
     "Users":[{
                "id":1,
                "newsPosts": [{
                                "id":1,
                                "message":"foo"
                             }]
             }],
   "newsPosts":[{
                 "id":2,
                 "message":"bar"
               }]   

   }
```

What i would want is to serialize only 1 or maybe 2 levels, So that the result would be:

```
   {
     "Users":[{
                "id":1,
                "newsPosts": []
             }],
   "newsPosts":[{
                 "id":2,
                 "message":"bar"
               }]   

   }
```

I have added a:

```
    json.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

This is to remove the referencelooping.

So in short: Is there any way of setting a maximum amount of nodes to serialize?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to serialize or deserialize a JSON Object to a certain depth in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453127/how-to-serialize-or-deserialize-a-json-object-to-a-certain-depth-in-c)

Comment: A custom JsonWriter and a custom ContractResolver seems to be the way to go. Thanks for noticing the duplicate.

Comment: over engineering here. Prepare the data you want to send, before returning it. EF is not appropriate for this, what you need is an extra layer, like someone else suggested already, use some DTOs and return those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it you have 2 options:

1. Write a custom serializer, or use an existing library if you can find one
2. Prepare the data you want the endpoints to send back before you attempt to serialise anything.

One of the best practices when it comes to APIs is to only send back the data which is needed because this affects the size of the data sent back.

Entity Framework works in a certain way by providing way too much and you want to limit that. A common way of solving this problem is to not have the API return Entity Framework entities. There are a number of reasons for that which can be researched separately.

So, one approach would be to start using DTOs to return data. This has a number of advantages:

1. You are in control of the data you send back and you don't need any custom serializer or yet another library.
2. You have control over the contents of the response, meaning sometimes you don't need all public properties in a class to be sent back, you need a subset and you can control that.
3. The API is not tightly coupled with Entity Framework and its entities anymore.

Disadvantages:

1. You now have another set of classes to deal with, however this complexity can be easily managed with something like AutoMapper, for example.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend mapping your domain classe(es) to custom DTO objects using something like AutoMapper, and then passing those for serialization.

Comment: It is not a good practice to recommend something without asking a question. E.g. may be there json will be used for using in generic contexts: like state handling, caching, logging...

Answer (score -1):

I'm not terribly familiar with Web API, but it seems like you'll want to make a custom MediaTypeFormatter that uses JavaScriptSerializer, which has a property to set a recursion limit.

[MSDN - JavaScriptSerializer.RecursionLimit Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.recursionlimit.aspx)

Another option is to make a custom formatter that uses JSON.NET which has the same sort of options.

Comment: Yes. Still want to use JSON.NET though. Seems as though there are more features on json.NET than javascriptserializer. So yea, seems like i want to go for the other option! Found a comparison here: http://json.codeplex.com/

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer.RecursionLimit  doesn't work for it. JavaScriptSerializer will  throw an exception in case of limit was achieved.

Answer (score -3):

Isn't this simply a question of how you construct the data to send from your get function ?

I mean the JSON serializer does its job by serializing all the data you give him, simply remove the data, or don't include it, and it won't get serialized.

If it's finer tuning you are looking for a custom JsonWriter is what you want, the link posted by Alex Filipovici give good details on what to do to achieve that.