# Serialize MouseEvent to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, dom-events

I need to serialize a MouseEvent to JSON but:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e))
});
```

prints only the first element of the event:

```
{"isTrusted": true}
```

I expected it to convert the whole MouseEvent to JSON including stuff like `offsetX`, `offsetY`.

I already tried [limiting JSON stringification depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466220/limit-json-stringification-depth) and [removing circular structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json) with [dojox.json.ref](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/json/ref.html), [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34519193/5508373), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24161582/5508373) and a few other ways. I figured circular structures were probably not the issue.

I currently work around it using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42284488/5508373) but there must be a better way.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547672/how-to-stringify-event-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stringify event object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547672/how-to-stringify-event-object)