# Limit recursion web.api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I'm building a web.api service. In this service I have a huge cache of a tree structure. This structure has a potential endless depth of Parent-Child relations. Due to performance reasons the whole tree is memory hashtable with links between objects. This ensures that I can retrieve the data very fast by selecting an item from the hashtable.

This method is called by the frontend (angularjs)

```
 public ElementRefItem GetElementById(string element, int depth)
 {
      var node = GetNodeFromTree(element)
      return element; <-- limit it to recursion depth.
 }
```

How can I limit the serializatoin of the json serializer that is used by web.api by the depth received in the metod? As a frontend I use Angularjs. When performing a query call it works when I return a List but when returning a string it complains that the data is not an array.

Edit:

I tried this solution: [How to serialize or deserialize a JSON Object to a certain depth in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453127/how-to-serialize-or-deserialize-a-json-object-to-a-certain-depth-in-c) Though this returns a string instead of a collection.

Edit:

After some tries is started to work with the above post (creating a HttpResponseMessage and transorming the first character to lower)
        property.PropertyName = Char.ToLowerInvariant(property.PropertyName[0]) + property.PropertyName.Substring(1);

I currently have one problem. Each end node has childs. For each child I get an empty object in my string array. I could handle this client side, though I would rather have it server side. Though I cannot find out how.

Comment: Did you try the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453127/how-to-serialize-or-deserialize-a-json-object-to-a-certain-depth-in-c

Comment: Yes. This gives back a string and a query object expects a collection and not a string :(

Comment: @Patrick What? Please explain. What query object?

Comment: Sorry, I was writing faster then I should have. I return now a collection. This is what angular needs as response on a query call. When returning a string it complains it is not an array.

Comment: Serialize to transport over the wire then you need to parse back to object form before you use the data. Show us how you are using this in javascript.

Comment: Sorry...but this is the wrong way to do a `asp.net-web-api` API. A hierarchical data structure lends it self well to a hierarchical Universal Resource Locator/Identifier.

Comment: refElementResource.query({ element: vm.element, depth: vm.depth.id, isArray: false }, function (data) {
                vm.rows = JSON.parse(data);
            });

Comment: There is a convention you should use to create a JSON with camelCase attributes. `jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();` . You can see other seetings to perform the serialization the way you need at http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm

Comment: @MAC, I know, but with using the custom way of the url you provided it does not use those resolvers anymore. Instead you create your own resolver and that does not have a camelCase formatter (and you can have only 1 contractresolver at a time.