# Limit json serialization depth

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have multiple EF and/or LinqToSql objects. I need to strigify them (log content for later debbuging).
I was trying to do it using json converter and JavaScriptSerializer. Unfortunately to prevent recursion i need to limit depth of serialization (like only to first level children).

How can I make it works, which library can do it, or is there a better way?

Don't tell me please that i need to make dto objects or other poco. I know i can make it work that way but because of code base size and number of required changes it is impractical.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen if the depth is exceeded?  There's [`JavaScriptSerializer.RecursionLimit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.recursionlimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will cause an exception to be thrown if the hierarchy is too deep.  If you don't want the exception, do you need to limit the recursion as it happens, or is it OK to postprocess the JSON to truncate the hierarchy?

Comment: I need to log data for later debugging/fixing/proving mistakes/etc. , and I may need first level children - at least we think first level should be enough. 
This mean not logging at all is useless for us. Size of the json is not a factor, problem is with infinite recursion and/or getting to far down the trees to the point where thousands of records are getting pulled.

Comment: You probably found a solution for this by now, but here is an option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453127/how-to-serialize-or-deserialize-a-json-object-to-a-certain-depth-in-c . This is for those who read this, since this post is above the one with the solution in the google results.