# How to Deserialize JSON object with arrays with objects using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have this JSON file which i want to Deserialize.

```
{
 "agencies":[
 {
  "id":44,
  "name":"National Aeronautics and Space Administration",  
  "countryCode":"USA",
  "abbrev":"NASA",
  "type":1,"infoURL":"http:\/\/www.nasa.gov",
  "wikiURL":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/National_Aeronautics_and_Space_Administration",
  "infoURLs":[
  "http:\/\/www.nasa.gov"
  ]
 }
],
"total":0,
"count":1,
"offset":0
}
```

I currenly have this code for getting the JSON and trying to deserialize it.

```
        RestClient client = new RestClient("https://launchlibrary.net/1.2/agency");
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest("NASA",Method.GET);
        var results = client.Execute(request).Content;

        MessageBox.Show(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(results).ToString());

        // Deserialize

        RootObject rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(results);

        MessageBox.Show(rootObject.agencies.Count.ToString());
```

And this

```
public class Agency
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string countryCode { get; set; }
    public string abbrev { get; set; }
    public int type { get; set; }
    public string infoURL { get; set; }
    public string wikiURL { get; set; }
    public List<string> infoURLs { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Agency> agencies { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public int offset { get; set; }
}
```

I can easily get to the things just inside the object such as `total` and `count` but not the array `agencies`.

How do I do this?

I'm only interested in the data inside the `agencies` array and not the `total`, `count` and `offset`

Comment: This seems fine.  What is the actual problem?

Comment: You have a string version of `infoURL` in your `Agency` class (as well as the list). I'd remove it and see if that clears it up.

Comment: I want to access the variables inside the agencies array from the JSON file. But i can't seem to do it. I can only access the variables in the root of the JSON object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to serialize or deserialize a JSON Object to a certain depth in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453127/how-to-serialize-or-deserialize-a-json-object-to-a-certain-depth-in-c)

Comment: Your deserialization code seems to work fine. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/pPW2H9

Comment: Agency a = rootObject .agencies[0];

Comment: Thank you. It works fine, there was another error that caused the problem.