# How do you limit indentation depth when serializing with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

When serializing an object using Newtonsoft.Json, is there a way to stop indentation of the serialized values after a given depth?

For example given the object in *Listing 1*, is there a way to subclass the `JsonConverter` or `JsonWriter` to indent only up to a certain level so that instead of the output in *Dump 1*, you get that in *Dump 2* or *Dump 3*?

**Listing 1**

```
var items = new[] {
    new { Name = "John",
          Age = 5,
          Address = new { Home = "No. 123, Oak Street", Email = "john@mail.com" },
          Extra = new { Serials = new[] { 20, 30, 40, 50 } }
    },
    new { Name = "Jean",
          Age = 2,
          Address = new { Home = "No. 321, Cliff Road", Email = "jean@mail.com" },
          Extra = new { Serials = new[] { 25, 35, 45, 55 } }
    }
};
```

**Dump 1: Fully Indented**

```
[
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 5,
    "Address": {
      "Home": "No. 123, Oak Street",
      "Email": "john@mail.com"
    },
    "Extra": {
      "Serials": [
        20,
        30,
        40,
        50
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jean",
    "Age": 2,
    "Address": {
      "Home": "No. 321, Cliff Road",
      "Email": "jean@mail.com"
    },
    "Extra": {
      "Serials": [
        25,
        35,
        45,
        55
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

**Dump 2: Two levels deep**

```
[
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 5,
    "Address": { "Home": "No. 123, Oak Street", "Email": "john@mail.com" },
    "Extra": { "Serials": [ 20, 30, 40, 50 ] }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jean",
    "Age": 2,
    "Address": { "Home": "No. 321, Cliff Road", "Email": "jean@mail.com" },
    "Extra": { "Serials": [ 25, 35, 45, 55 ] }
  }
]
```

**Dump 3: Three levels deep**

```
[
  {
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 5,
    "Address": {
      "Home": "No. 123, Oak Street",
      "Email": "john@mail.com"
    },
    "Extra": {
      "Serials": [ 20, 30, 40, 50 ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Jean",
    "Age": 2,
    "Address": {
      "Home": "No. 321, Cliff Road",
      "Email": "jean@mail.com"
    },
    "Extra": {
      "Serials": [ 25, 35, 45, 55 ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: I would question why you need this, json is a data format that is a readable, not primarily a display tool. Though to answer, I am not sure how you would achieve this easily in Json.Net or Text.Json, i guess you could do some post processing and parse indentation levels, and remove new lines and spaces... seems hacky though

Comment: Is this question answer your questions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10453127/how-to-serialize-or-deserialize-a-json-object-to-a-certain-depth-in-c

Comment: @Developer: No, it doesn't answer my question. I am not attempting to **stop serializing** beyond a certain depth. What I want is to **stop indentation** after a given depth. The [solution provided by Brian Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65558459) addresses my needs. Thank you

Comment: @TheGeneral for diffing. Time for diffing is function of number of lines. Too much lines = diff tool takes hour to try to pair lines with no relation. Too few lines (eg no indentation at all = just one line) diff tool is not usefull

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can cap the indentation depth by subclassing the [`JsonTextWriter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextWriter.htm) like this:

```
public class CustomIndentingJsonTextWriter : JsonTextWriter
{
    public int? MaxIndentDepth { get; set; } 

    public CustomIndentingJsonTextWriter(TextWriter writer) : base(writer)
    {
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    }

    public override void WriteStartArray()
    {
        base.WriteStartArray();
        if (MaxIndentDepth.HasValue && Top > MaxIndentDepth.Value) 
            Formatting = Formatting.None;
    }

    public override void WriteStartObject()
    {
        base.WriteStartObject();
        if (MaxIndentDepth.HasValue && Top > MaxIndentDepth.Value) 
            Formatting = Formatting.None;
    }

    public override void WriteEndArray()
    {
        base.WriteEndArray();
        if (MaxIndentDepth.HasValue && Top <= MaxIndentDepth.Value) 
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    }

    public override void WriteEndObject()
    {
        base.WriteEndObject();
        if (MaxIndentDepth.HasValue && Top <= MaxIndentDepth.Value) 
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    }
}
```

You can create a helper method to make it easy to use the writer:

```
public static string SerializeWithCustomIndenting(object obj, int? maxIdentDepth = null)
{
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    using (CustomIndentingJsonTextWriter jw = new CustomIndentingJsonTextWriter(sw))
    {
        jw.MaxIndentDepth = maxIdentDepth;
        JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
        ser.Serialize(jw, obj);
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
string json = SerializeWithCustomIndenting(yourObject, 2);  // indent to 2 levels max
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XhwsGF